# Запятая " в связи"

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая: "В связи с просьбой устроителей  организовать работу буфета, просим Вас дать указание о предоставлении помещения"?
Заранее благодарна!
С уважением,
Анна

Answer (score 4):

Это факультативное обособление.Обязательно обособляется только оборот с НЕСМОТРЯ НА.

Оборот обособляется, если требуется обозначить его границы (чтобы предложение не выглядело двусмысленным):Во избежание неверного понимания фразы директором, были внесены изменения в документ. – Во избежание неверного понимания фразы, директором были внесены изменения в документ.

Оборот не обособляется, если он входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу.

В остальных случаях можно говорить о факультативности обособления оборота (в зависимости от степени его распространенности, близости к основной части предложения, порядка слов в предложении, авторского замысла и других факторов).

Обычно обособляются обороты, которые:

•располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым: Достаточно надавить пальцем на глазное яблоко, и все реальные предметы – в отличие от галлюцинаций – раздвоятся. Левая стена, в противовес правой,отражала концепцию ранней смерти.  И мать, наперекор всем несчастьям, собрала меня, хотя до того никто из нашей деревни в районе не учился.

•находятся не в начале и не в конце предложения: Ровно в три часа, в соответствии с трудовым законодательством, принес ключи доктор наук Амвросий Амбруазович Выбегалло.

•содержат объяснение того, о чем говорится в предложении, и выделяются интонационно: ...Детям, по причине малолетства, не определили никаких должностей.

Обычно обособляются (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу) обороты с отглагольными предлогами включая,исключая, исходя из, начиная с, невзирая на, несмотря на, смотря по, судя по, а также ограничительно-выделительные обороты с предлогами вопреки, за исключением, кроме,независимо от, помимо.

Обычно не обособляются обороты с предлогами вместо, в ответ на, в результате, вроде, за счет, наподобие, напротив, не доходя, по поводу, ради, спустя.

В спорных случаях окончательное решение о постановке знаков препинания принимает автор текста.

"В связи" не входит ни в одну группу, он факультативен, и я бы здесь НЕ стала выделять, потому что оборот стоит вначале и предложное сочетание  В СВЯЗИ С можно заменить непроизводным предлогом "ИЗ-ЗА", выделительной функции здесь нет.

Comment: Людмила, если прочитаете, не могли бы прокомментировать подобный вопрос.http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420838

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, это обособленное распространенное обстоятельство с производным предлогом В СВЯЗИ.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ  (ОБЩАЯ ТЕОРИЯ ВОПРОСА)

Распространенные обстоятельства, выраженные существительными  с производными предлогами,  обычно обособляются, так как в большинстве случаев являются аналогами соответствующих  обстоятельственных придаточных предложений, на которые их можно заменить: В связи с сильным волнением на море, катер был вынужден вернуться.

Обстоятельства с производными предлогами не обособляются, если в предложении они составляют основное сообщение.  Обычно это касается нераспространенных обстоятельств  в начале или в конце предложения: Работы прекращены в связи с аварией.

Comment: Это предложение и прочитать-то без паузы невозможно, запятая ставится обязательно. В нашей пунктуации действует интонационно-грамматический принцип постановки знаков препинания, поэтому рассуждения о наличии или отсутствии выделительной функции или замена предлога В СВЯЗИ на предлог ИЗ-ЗА непонятно какое отношение имеют к этим принципам. "Просим предоставить помещение для буфета в связи с просьбой устроителей" - вот в этом  случае запятая не нужна, но пришлось перестроить структуру предложения и сократить его объем.
И еще пример:Отряд рисковал, отправившись в путь несмотря на непогоду.

Comment: Не всегда пауза в речи соответствует знаку препинания на письме. Согласна с Людмилой, в соответствии с правилами обязателен для выделения только оборот "с несмотря на".

Comment: 1) В связи с производственной необходимостью просим...
2)В связи с тем, что устроители выразили пожелание, чтобы им организовали работу буфета, просим Вас... Суть предложения одна и та же, но в случае 1) запятая не нужна, а в случае 2) обязательна. Как это увязать с логикой? Правила должны быть математически отточенными, с минимумом исключений. Запомнить все тонкости невозможно, чувствовать язык - это дано редким, как абсолютный музыкальный слух. В связи с производственной необходимостью надо упрощать формулировки Правил орфографии и пунктуации. Если очень нужно, то это возможно!

Comment: Не всегда пауза в речи соответствует знаку препинания на письме, но интонацию простого предложения всегда можно отличить от интонации предложения с обособленными членами.  Можно  сказать еще много слов о структуре и интонации, а также  о необходимости обособить оборот, который по объему составляет половину предложения, но я не уверена, что меня услышат.

Comment: Поэтому давайте проведем эксперимент и еще в большей степени распространим предложение:"В связи с неоднократными просьбами устроителей организовать работу буфета на предприятии, просим Вас дать указание о предоставлении помещения". Скажите, Ларf, вы здесь тоже не поставите запятую, так как с вышеизложенной формулировкой правил согласны?

Comment: Знак возможен, но не является обязательным.